# How the use Docker exec to update code into a running container

Tags: docker

I am using docker-compose to manage Docker. Now suppose I want to update a source code in one of the Docker containers.

Can I do it using the exec but then how to copy the code from host to running container ?

Or is there any better solution to do the above task ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad practice.
You need to use Continuous Integration rebuild docker image (see Dockerfile) every time when source code changed.

Comment: can you suggest some suitable CI/ CD lib or software  for the same ?

Comment: Drone CI, Jenkins, Travis CI

Answer (score 0):

In terms of doing it once to verify how this is done you can use the `docker cp` command from the host machine -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

But I agree with Meiram, this is bad practice. You want to be able to have the ability to revert back to a previous version of not only the code but also the container.

There is a very good tutorial here integrating Docker/DockerHub with Github, Jenkins, and even Sonarqube.

https://medium.com/@hakdogan/an-end-to-end-tutorial-to-continuous-integration-and-continuous-delivery-by-dockerize-jenkins-f5b9b45b610d